# My printer don't print the document when setup printer server by raspberry pi

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cups

I'm setting up a printer server by raspberry pi zero w then i print on Windows.

I installed cups and samba, add printer online, but when i print a document from Windows it doesn't print the document i need
My printer is Samsung ML-2160 Series

```
-12345X@PJL Comment "Username : phaml"
@PJL COMMENT USERNAME= "phaml"
@PJL SET COPIES = 1
@PJL SET COLORMODE=MONO
@PJL SET RESOLUTION 600
@PJL SET IMAGEQUALITY = 0
@PJL DEFAULT SERVICEDATE=20190614
@PJL SET DUPLEX=OFF
@PJL SET PAPERTYPE=OFF
@PJL SET BANNERSHEET = OFF
```

Comment: Hello! I have the exact same printer and problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install the printer using this driver: https://mega.nz/file/LgUnySKL#2wXWs2nexQkARQbz7VjefTbLv3q28CK09jKqppHKZqQ
(Choose "Have Disk.." when asked for the driver and navigate to the extracted zip file)

I had the exact same problem on one machine but on a different Windows 10 machine I could just select the correct driver without any issues. The working windows installation is already a bit older so it seems like the working driver for this printer disappeared in new windows versions? At least that's my guess.
The zip file above is just the standard windows driver (located under C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository) copied from the working machine.

Comment: What is wrong with [official drivers for universal driver V3.00.15.00:01 from trusted web sites](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/SS/SL-M3370FD/SamsungUniversalPrintDriver3.exe) ?

Comment: Did not work for me. Produced the exact problem mentioned above.